# overflow on table td

Tags: css

How can you put an overflow property on a cell in a table?

http://jsfiddle.net/e8Bxj/

```
table {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

td.content {
    overflow:auto;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>hmm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="content">
            sadfasf<br>
            sadfasf<br>
            sadfasf<br>
            sadfasf<br>
            sadfasf<br>
            sadfasf<br>
            sadfasf<br>
            sadfasf<br>
            sadfasf<br>
            sadfasf<br>
            sadfasf<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hmm</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the overflowing content in div.

http://jsfiddle.net/e8Bxj/1/

Answer (score 1):

you just simply add

```
display:inline-block;
```

into the td , like this

```
id.content
{
display:inline-block;
overflow:auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/e8Bxj/2/)